# Convergence Analysis of A Vector Sequence with Discretization Recurrences (with Toy Examples)

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, convergence-divergence, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

I'm confused by how to analyse if a vector sequence is convergent or not. Here I first post the original problem as follows:

(Although this post is long, the problem meaning is easy to understand but **how to prove it** is very hard for me.)

(You may first jump over the original problem below and take a glance at my **toy example**.)

---

**1. Problem:**

Given a sequence length value $T\in\mathbb{N}$, a threshold $K\in\mathbb{N}$ and target summation $S\in\mathbb{N}$, an N-dimensional vector sequence $\{\mathbf{v}_t\}_{t=0}^{T}$ is produced by:

- The first item $\mathbf{v}_0\in\mathbb{R}^N$ is given by random generation. All its elements are non-negative and their summation is a non-negative integer denoted by $S\in\mathbb{N}$ that satisfies: $0\le S\le KN$;
- The subsequent items is produced by the following steps (procedure):

$~~~~~~~$(1) Initialize $\mathbf{v}_t:=\mathbf{v}_{t-1}$;

$~~~~~~~$(2) Calculate the average error between the element summation and $S$, i.e., let $\delta_t:=\text{average}(\mathbf{v}_t)-(S/N)$;

$~~~~~~~$(3) Force the summation of its all elements to be $S$, i.e., $\mathbf{v}_t:=\mathbf{v}_t-\delta_t$, here each element of $\mathbf{v}_t$ is reduced by $\delta_t$;

$~~~~~~~$(4) Force all elements to be integers in $[0,K]$, i.e., $\mathbf{v}_t:=\text{round}(\text{clip}_{0,K}(\mathbf{v}_t))$, where $\text{round}(\cdot)$ and $\text{clip}_{0,K}(\cdot)$ are element-wise operator, they calculate the new vector element values dimension-by-dimension.

The complete recurrence formula should be:

$$
\mathbf{v}_t:=\text{round}(\text{clip}_{0,K}(\mathbf{v}_{t-1}-[\text{average}(\mathbf{v}_{t-1})-(S/N)])).
$$

Is $\{\mathbf{v}_t\}_{t=0}^{T}$ convergent or not when $T\rightarrow\infty$?

(Some above expressions may be informal but do not affect the meaning of this problem)

---

There is a toy example (created by myself) that may be helpful to understand the original problem:

**2. My Example (may be a little weird but not impactive):**

I have three children ($N=3$) and ten stamps ($S=10$). My children weigh $90$kg, $6$kg and $4$kg (the first one may be a teenager and the latter two may be little baby boys), respectively, so at the beginning, I want to give them $9$, $0.6$ and $0.4$ stamps, respectively.

But there are three constrains. Firstly, I think a child can not have more than four stamps ($K=4$). Secondly, the stamps can only be given one-by-one and one single stamp can not be cut, divided or shared (the stamps given to each child must be with a non-negative integer number). Thirdly, I only have ten stamps in total, and I want to try my best to distribute them all (the summation of all elements should be $S$ or close to $S$).

So I perform the above mentioned procedure as follows:

$~~~~~~~$(1) I initialize the stamp number vector: $(9, 0.6, 0.4)$;

- First round:

$~~~~~~~$(2) I calculate the average error $\delta$, and found that it is zero;

$~~~~~~~$(3) I clip each element into $[0,4]$ and round them, then I get: $(4, 1, 0)$;

- Second round:

$~~~~~~~$(4) I calculate the average error $\delta=(5-10)/3=-1.67$;

$~~~~~~~$(5) I correct the stamp number vector: $(4, 1, 0)-(-1.67)=(5.67,2.67,1.67)$;

$~~~~~~~$(6) I clip each element into $[0,4]$ and round them, then I get: $(4, 3, 2)$;

- Third round:

$~~~~~~~$(7) I calculate the average error $\delta=(9-10)/3=-0.33$;

$~~~~~~~$(8) I correct the stamp number vector: $(4, 3, 2)-(-0.33)=(4.33,3.33,2.33)$;

$~~~~~~~$(9) I clip each element into $[0,4]$ and round them, then I get: $(4, 3, 2)$.

I find that the stamp vector sequence is converged, so I stop, give the children four, three and two stamps, respectively, and keep one stamp.

---

**3. My Efforts (may be not a correct idea):**

I'm trying to prove that the average error sequence $\{\delta_t\}$ is absolutely convergent, i.e., I was trying to show that:

$$
0\le |\delta_{t}|\le|\delta_{t-1}|,
$$

but I was failed. And I think if $\{\delta_t\}$ is convergent, we can not say that $\{\mathbf{v}_t\}$ is convergent.

May be I need to prove that $\{\delta_t\}$ is convergent to zero? However, I empirically find that $\{|\delta_t|\}$ may only be convergent to a non-negative number in most cases (please see below).

Nevertheless, I simulated the absolute average error sequence $\{|\delta_t|\}$ by a toy Python program and observed that $\{|\delta_t|\}$ may be convergent:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 100  # vector dimension
T = 30  # max sequence length
S = 51200  # target sum of vector elements
K = 1024  # max value of each element

for _ in range(1000):  # 1000 test instances
    v = np.random.rand(N)  # uniformly distributed random vector
    v = (v / np.sum(v)) * S  # normalize to make the element sum be S
    abs_delta_list = []  # all absolute values of deltas
    for t in range(T + 1):  # t = 0, 1, 2, ..., T
        delta = np.mean(v) - (S / N)  # average error
        v -= delta  # force the sum to be S
        v = np.round(np.clip(v, 0, K))  # force all elements to be intergers in [0, K]
        abs_delta_list.append(np.abs(delta))  # collect abs(delta)
    plt.plot(abs_delta_list, color='blue')  # plot curve

plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('abs(delta)')
plt.savefig('abs_delta.png', dpi=600)
```

I obtained:

$(N=100, T=30, S=5120, K=1024)$

[image: t-abs(delta)]

$(N=10, T=30, S=5120, K=1024)$

[image]

(Obviously, $\delta_1$ is zero).

---

**4. Update:**

I've solved this problem with the help of @antkam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline of proof that the vector converges.

Part A: The key observation is this: let $v^i_t$ denote the $i$-th component of $v_t$, then $ \forall i \neq j, \forall t:$

- bigger element remains bigger (or equal), i.e. $v^i_t \ge v^j_t \implies v^i_{t+1} \ge v^j_{t+1}$;
- absolute difference between elements is monotonically decreasing, i.e. $|v^i_t - v^j_t| \ge |v^i_{t+1} - v^j_{t+1}|$.

These follow relatively easily from your rules.

Now because you are dealing with integers, these imply for any pair, $v^i - v^j$ must converge, because the absolute difference converges (it cannot decrease forever) and which-is-bigger is preserved.

Thus we know the vector's "shape" converges, but it is still possible the whole vector shifts up and down by a constant amount across all elements.

Part B: Prove that it doesn't oscillate like that.  Once the "shape" converges, say to $w$, all possible future vectors are of the form $w + n$ for some $n \in N$, and you should be able to prove that every step brings $v$ closer to the $w+n$ which minimizes $\delta$.

There is a bit of special case where two adjacent solutions $w+n, w+n+1$ both minimize $\delta$ at $\delta = 0.5$ and you will need some argument with the $round()$ function to prove it settles on one of them.

Comment: Hi @antkam, thank you very much for your kind help with constructive suggestions. I've successfully proved the vector convergency.